# I don't know how to refer to fonts on my ftp server

Tags: html, css, ftp

I am creating some text in html and I've tried using @fontface, which of course work.
The problem is how could I import fonts from my ftp server. I don't really get what path or something like this should be in url in @fontface

Comment: @font-face https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face expects the font resource to be retrieved through a url() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url) .. and the address is supposed to be http/https not ftp

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add your fonts somewhere in the path of your web server (where html pages are located) so your `font-face` will be something like:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  src: url("/path/to/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
       url("/path/to/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff") format("woff");
}
```